# Programmatically load Python Module/Functions

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, cocoa

- My main application is in Objective-C/Cocoa (OS X)
- The main application is "extended" using Python "plugins"
- We're making use of the Python framework

This is the code I'm using as a "bridge" to execute a specific script:

```
from Foundation import *
from AppKit import *

import imp
import sys

class ppPluginBridge(NSObject):
    @classmethod
    def loadModuleAtPath_functionName_arguments_documents_(self, path, func, args,docs):

        f = open(path)
        try:
             mod = imp.load_module('plugin', f, path, (".py", "r", imp.PY_SOURCE))
             realfunc = getattr(mod, func, None)
             if realfunc is not None:
                 realfunc(*tuple(args))
        except Exception as e:
             docs.showConsoleError_('%s' % e)
        finally:
             f.close()
             return NO

        return YES
```

So this function takes a script in `path` and loads/executes it.

Now, what I need is : make some python classes/functions/modules automatically available to the final script (either declared externally or - preferably - in my `ppPluginBridge.py` file).

How can that be done?

Comment: note: [`finally: ... return NO`](http://ideone.com/91kZPH) means that the function always returns `NO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd do loading something more like this:

```
>>> class Thingus:
...     def __init__(self):
...         module = __import__('string')
...         setattr(self,module.__name__,module)
... 
>>> thing = thingus()
>>> thing.string
<module 'string' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/string.pyc'>
>>>
```

Note that this uses the built-in import function to import and is able to take standard module names, like `this.that` rather than some direct path to a Python file. This is cleaner. You just need to make sure the modules are proper modules, and are within the path.

As for specifying what things you'd like to import, why not just use a list within ppPluginBridge.py? You'd just do something like:

```
plugin_modules = [ 'plugins.loader', 'plugins.serializer' ]
```

...or what have you. Python is very expressive, so there's nothing wrong with making a Python module a configuration file in itself. Configuration files should, of course, be properly separate, and ignored by version control systems after their defaults are established so that individual installations can change them.